# Facing issue with makefile for Hello pass in llvm

Tags: makefile, llvm

I am new to llvm, am trying to write a pass for llvm Hello 
I have downloaded and built llvm in linux machine by following the link  http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html

I have tried to write a pass by following the link  http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

I have copied the makefile specified in the link to the Hello folder in llvm and tried to perform a make. But I encounter the below error.
Makefile:14: ../../../Makefile.common: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../../../Makefile.common'.  Stop.

I understand that it is not able to find the Makefile.common. But most of the stuff in llvm is readonly and downloaded from the svn repository.

Can anyone assist me with this issue? Am I missing anything, am I following the correct way?

Is there any better tutorial anyone can refer?
TIA

Answer (score 2):

LLVM now builds with CMake, so that old Makefile won't work. The same tutorial you linked points out how to [write the CMakeLists.txt](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#cmake-out-of-source-pass).

### Out-of-tree build

Set up a directory structure like this:

```
HelloPassProject
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── HelloPass
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── HelloPass.cpp
```

So there's a top-level `HelloPassProject`, which contains the root `CMakeLists.txt`, a `build` directory where we'll build our pass and a `HelloPass` directory containing the actual pass source and the pass `CMakeLists.txt`.

Contents of `HelloPassProject/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")
include(AddLLVM)

add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(HelloPass)
```

Contents of `HelloPassProject/HelloPass/CMakeLists.txt` (list your sources here):

```
add_llvm_loadable_module(LLVMHelloPass HelloPass.cpp)
```

To build against an installed LLVM:

```
cd HelloPassProject/build
cmake ..
make
```

To build against an LLVM you've built from source (let's say it's been built in `~/llvm-project/build`):

```
cd HelloPassProject/build
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/llvm-project/build ..
make
```

### In-tree build

You just need the `HelloPass` subdirectory from the out-of-tree build. Copy that inside `<LLVM root>/lib/Transform`. Add a `add_subdirectory(HelloPass)` line to `<LLVM root>/lib/Transform/CMakeLists.txt`. Build LLVM as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrea , I have tried doing a cmake by editing the CMakeLists.txt file in the <pass folder> and the one in the directory that contains the <pass folder>
I see the following error message
(minksy)% sudo cmake ../
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_llvm_loadable_module):
  Unknown CMake command "add_llvm_loadable_module".
 I have included these lines in CMakeLists.txt
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")
include(AddLLVM)
May I know where I might be wrong

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This is much better than the llvm guide. Specifically, what helped me was the prefix path when llvm is built from source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Makefile.common under llvm.3.9.0-src, i.e. your llvm source root. So that should not be your problem.

Note that there are some make variables to set in Makefile.common.